# RSS feed reader that sends email

Tags: linux, ubuntu, rss

I'm looking for an RSS feed reader that monitors a feed for a keyword(s), and then sends me an email when that keyword(s) shows up in the feed.

Ideally it would either be a web-based service, or a cli-based linux program/project (Debian).

Note: I'm not looking to forward a feed to my email, but to notify me when a key word comes up

Answer (score 1):

According to  [this](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=864276) you can do a couple things using Google News and create feeds using advanced Google search techniques.

Near the bottom is a link to a couple programs which you can test together and see if they do what you want.